# How to check whether an activity is running or not

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether activity is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934050/check-whether-activity-is-active)

I want to show a progress dialog on the screen if the activity is showing. But when the activity window is not showing, it will not do anything. Please suggest, how do I check whether my activity is showing or not?

Comment: I've provided the solution at this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8963867/1079001.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for quick responses.. but i think i figured my answer. I try-catched the part where i was starting the progress dialog.

Sample code --

```
try {
        pd2.show();
    } catch (WindowManager.BadTokenException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

So if my activity is in on the top, it will show the progress dialog, otherwise it will throw a BadTokenException which is handled using try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the Activity [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html). Specific methods get called based on your actvities current state, whether running, whether paused, killed, etc.

Comment: You have to start action onResume() and stop it onPause().