# How to know what activities has been started from a context?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen-lock

I have a `LockScreenReceiver` extend `BroadcastReceiver` class, and want to start Lock Screen Intent every time the screen has been turn off. But how can I check the `Context` has been start the given activity already, so I don't have to start it all over again.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        isScreenOn = false;
        LockServiceManager.getInstance().Initialize(context);
        Intent lockIntent = LockServiceManager.getInstance().getLockScreenActivityIntent();
        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(lockIntent);
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        isScreenOn = true;
        // TODO Start activity if the device has been sleep for a long time.
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent lockIntent = LockServiceManager.getInstance().getLockScreenActivityIntent();
        lockIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(lockIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934050/check-whether-activity-is-active

Comment: If your alarm receiver called Context.startService().....

Comment: [http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html]
I hope its useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onResume(){   
 Filter = new IntentFilter();
    Filter.addAction("RECEIVED_ACTION");
    activity.registerReceiver(Receiver, Filter);
}
```

I hope it is useful for you.