# Is there an event handler to know that an activity is displayed on the screen?

Tags: android

I want to make a database request whenever the main activity is dislpayed on the screen , the main activity is the one defined in the manifest file :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

if I start another activity by clicking a menu item for example , then when I finish it by pressing the back button or the code executes a `finish` command then I want the database request to be launched because at this moment it is the main activity which is displayed. So how to know that the **main** activity is displayed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `Boolean` in `onResume()`, and `onPause()` could get you your desired effect. Once the activity is resumed, your code in `onResume()` would change the `Boolean` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, which then could activate a `Listener` you have set up on that `Boolean`.

EDIT: You also have to set code in `onPause()` to change the `Boolean` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

For some related questions that have been answered, here you go:
[Check whether activity is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934050/check-whether-activity-is-active)
and
[Android: how do I check if activity is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446565/android-how-do-i-check-if-activity-is-running)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the activity Life Circle, You shoud put your code into onResume().
Hope it can help :)
Image for Activiy life circle [Activity Life circle](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Android_Logcat-Activity-Starts.jpg)