# Set different activities for pending intent of notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I am currently facing the problem of setting pending action for two different activities to notification.

I have a ParentActivity and a ChildActivity. I want open ChildActivity on notification click if currently it is running or paused, otherwise start ParentActivity.

I tried this :

```
 .........

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ParentActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    .............
```

Above is not working for me. Everytime ChildActivity is starting on notification click.

And also as Faruk answered, I dont want this. Creating a notification's pending intent by checking ChildActivity's current state will not work.
Suppose notification created when ChildActivity was running but after creating the notification, user killed the app. So after killing the app, If user will click on notification then ChildActivity will start. I don't want that. I want if ChildActivity is not running or paused then ParentActivity should be started.

How can I achieve this?
Please help.

Comment: Please post your code..@Sar

Comment: Try this:- PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(contex,0,resultIntent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your `Notification` launch a simple dispatch `Activity`. This `Activity` does the following in `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate(...);
if (ChildActivity.running) {
    // ChildActivity is running, so redirect to it
    Intent childIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
    // Add necessary flags, maybe FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it depends what the rest of your app looks like
    childIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(childIntent);
} else {
    // Child is not running, so redirect to parent
    Intent parentIntent = new Intent(this, ParentIntent.class);
    // Add necessary flags, maybe FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it depends what the rest of your app looks like
    parentIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(parentIntent);
}
finish();
```

In `ChildActivity` do this:

```
public static boolean running; // Set when this Activity is active
```

In `ChildActivity.onCreate()` add this:

```
running = true;
```

In `ChildActivity.onDestroy()` add this:

```
running = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

While there may be several ways to achieve this, following is the one I can think of.

First, you should get whether ChildActivity is active or not, through this link

[Check whether activity is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934050/check-whether-activity-is-active)

Store this in some variable childActive, then you can initialize different notificationIntents checking the value without using task TaskStackBuilder.

For example;

```
Intent notificationIntent = null;
if(childActive)
    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
else
    notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ParentActivity.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Faruk. But there is a problem with this way. Suppose notification created when ChildActivity was running but after notification created, user killed the app. So after killing app, If user will click on notification then ChildActivity will start.
I don't want that. I want if ChildActivity is not running or paused then PArentActivity should be started.